# How to align QLabel text to label's right edge

Tags: python, pyqt

The label is given a fixed width via `label.setFixedWidth(200)`.
The text inside of label is shorter then label's width. As it is now the label text is being centered within a label. But I would like the text to be aligned with the label's right side so the text right side is edge by edge to lineEdit widget left edge.

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.resize(720, 480)
        cWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(cWidget)

        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(cWidget)

        label = QtGui.QLabel("     Label Text Value: ")
        label.setFixedWidth(200)
        layout.addWidget(label)

        textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        textEdit.setMaximumHeight(14)
        layout.addWidget(textEdit)

        button=QtGui.QPushButton("Browse")
        layout.addWidget(button)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    frame = MainWindow()
    frame.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you don't want to use spacers, this does this trick:

```
label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
```